# Pulling the wrong String Resource in androidTests

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I was running into trouble testing against JSON responses with some androidTests. At first I was pulling in a raw JSON file, that was not working correctly, I thought I was just going about it all wrong.

After that I just threw the JSON into a regular StringRes file and I was not getting the expected JSON string.

The problem is, that I am trying to only have it under the androidTest and not part of the main project so that I won't ship my app with test data in it.

For the test I have the structure:

```
src > main > res > values > strings.xml

With a string resource of: 
        <string name="some_string_in_resources">Here is a test</string>
```

and

```
src > androidTest > res > values > strings.xml

With a string resource of:
        <string name="some_other_string_in_test">Here is a test</string>
```

Then I made a test:

```
public class StringResourceTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void testStringResources() {
        Assert.assertEquals(getContext().getResources().getString(com.somecoolurl.myapplication.test.R.string.some_other_string_in_test),
                getContext().getString(R.string.some_string_in_resources));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[res/drawable-v21/abc_action_bar_item_background_material.xml]> but was:<[Here is a test]>
at com.somecoolurl.myapplication.StringResourceTest.testStringResources(StringResourceTest.java:13)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)

Tests ran to completion.
```

I feel that I am doing things correctly, but obviously I am not getting the expected results. How should I set up these tests in a way that I won't ship test data with the app when I release it into the store?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?  I am having a similar issue...